# upgrade form 14.04 to 16.04 is stuck, Help!

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I follow the instructions, cleaned up the disk and /boot and started the upgrade, it seems to work fine until I touched the screen. The Terminal small window shrink to one line. The installation seems to hang at the following stage:

[[image: enter link description here]]

I need Help, How to continue?
What to type at the **more**
 prompt. Nothing I tried did anything.

Comment: How do I add the screen picture?

Comment: The last message is 'Configuring libssl 1.0.0 (i386)', anyway.

Comment: Can you click in the terminal area and see if the cursor goes from outline to white?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
Since I got no answer, I aborted the stuck installation. Then tried to reboot the computer, to my surprise it started with alphanumeric ttys (6 of them) on 16.04.1.
I started to work on it, tried to burn a DVD, some library was missing for 'brasero'. I started to install following hints that I got from the system, and finally after some commands, that I list below, the system asked for reboot. Following the reboot I have a full functioning 16.04.1 (at least so it seems now).

The commands I typed following hints from the system:
$ sudo apt-get install brasero
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

## Then again, I tried

$ sudo apt-get install brasero
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo reboot

If more explanation is needed, I'll be glad to try and provide it.
Regards.